# tracking user invite through oauth login

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm building an app where the user will receive an invite to join a team.
The invite link is unique to the user, and when the user hits the sign-up page, they they can login using oauth (google).

After the user goes through the authentication and gets passed back to my app, I need to get their invite code, so I can look it up in the db and add them to the correct team.

I thought I could pass a `state` variable to the oauth provider which would get passed back to me like `auth?state=INVITE_CODE`, but when I send a state parameter to google in my auth request, it doesn't respond at all.

What's the best way to accomplish this?
I'm using express passport if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was WAY over thinking this, so hopefully this will help somebody else. 
If you look at the `res.headers.referer` it is actually your original link, not the link from the oauth provider, which I expected.